# docker-compose throwing "ModuleNotFoundError" with pandas

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, containers

I am trying to containerize a very simple Flask API that connects to mongodb. For the API's output, I am using the pandas module. However, when I run 'docker-compose up', I get the following error:

app_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1  |   File "app.py", line 6, in 
app_1  |     import pandas as pd
app_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
app:
  build: .
  command: python -u app.py
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - .:/app

  links:
    - db
db:
  image: mongo:latest
```

My requirements.txt is as follows:

```
pymongo==3.11.4
Flask==1.1.2
pandas==1.1.3
```

Since I have pandas in the requirements.txt, shouldn't the container have the module? I'm not getting this error for pymongo or Flask, which is why I am curious. I'm fairly new to Docker, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

#### `DOCKERFILE`

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app

ADD . .
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python","app.py"]
```

##### `ENTRYPOINT` (and `CMD`)

You would be better placed running the Python app from within the container. Add: `ENTRYPOINT ["python","app.py"]` to the end of the Dockerfile.

> **NOTE** Docker `ENTRYPOINT` is the default (entrypoint) when running the container. It's a good practice to set this to the binary (i.e. `python app.py`) that you want to run when you run the container. Docker `ENTRYPOINT` can be overridden with Docker Compose `entrypoint`. There's also `CMD`. It's good practice to set this to the default arguments and flags that you want to run when you run the container. In the `docker-compose.yml`, `command` overrides Docker `CMD`.

Then you can run the container standalone to test it:

```sh
docker build \
--tag=68567602:v1 \
--file=./Dockerfile \
.

docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--publish=5000:5000 \
68567602:v1
```

##### `WORKDIR`

In the Dockerfile, it's a good idea to set the `WORKDIR` first to save duplicating the reference, i.e.

#### `docker-compose.yml`

```
app:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"

db:
  image: mongo:latest
```

##### `command`

The `docker-compose.yml` need not include `command` unless you want to override the container's `CMD` settings

##### `volumes`

The `docker-compose.yml` should **not** overwrite the container's `/app` directory with your host's `/app` directory. Doing this overwrites the e.g. `pip install` that you ran and is causing the problem

##### `links`

I think you don't want the `links` entry. Your python app can reference the MongoDB service by the name you gave it `db`

Comment: What you said about volumes resolved the issue. The program still has problems, but I'm going to work them out. Thanks! :D